# Product brand (attribute, category or both)?

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1, performance, best-practice

I am fairly new to Magento module development, and I am dealing with catalog/product pages at the moment.

I have seen our clients using different approaches when dealing with storing product brands.

1. Store them under the default manufacturer attribute.
2. Store them under a custom attribute (which is named brand, or whatever)
3. Store brands as categories and assign the product to that brand/category. The product then has multiple categories e.g: *['Apple', 'laptop']* or *['Apple', 'ipad']*, etc. Sometimes even *['Brands', 'Apple', 'categories', 'laptop']*

**So my first question is whether there is a best practice to storing product brands?**

My module requires extraction of the product brand attribute, and in [1,2] approaches, it is pretty straight forward. I simply get the product attribute text of brand attribute **(I ask them to specify the brand attribute in module configuration)**.

However [3] is a bit different approach, so I would also want to know **what would be the best way in Magento achieving that**

The way I am doing it now is I take all product categories, and check whether the category is a child of a 'Brands' category. **Is this performant enough for production use?**:

```
private function getProductBrandFromCategory($product, $parentCategoryIdToLookFor) {
    $categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();

    foreach($categoryCollection as $_productCategory) {
        $_parentCategories = $_productCategory->getParentCategories();

        foreach($_parentCategories as $_parentCategory) {
            if($parentCategoryIdToLookFor != $_productCategory->getId() && in_array($parentCategoryIdToLookFor, $_parentCategory->getPathIds())) {
                return $_parentCategory->getName();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now obviously I do now want to have different module versions per different set-ups, so I would like to come up with a generalised solution. What are the ways of solving this kind of problems, I am sure I can't be the only one dealing with such issues.

My thought on the generalised version is to have two fields in module configuration, a dropdown and a text field. The dropdown would contain all product attributes, and if they have [1,2] approach, they would select the appropriate attribute name from the dropdown, and leave the text field empty.

For set-up [3], they would leave the dropdown untouched and enter the name of the category, under which all the brands are stored.

**Would this be a good approach towards that?**

I know it might look like a long question, so please tell me if something is unclear. Looking forward to the answers.